# setpci on boot?

Tags: boot, command-line

I have a Gateway nv78 with ubuntu 20.04 installed.  When I boot, I have a black screen but the ports work fine with external monitors.  After I execute sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00 in terminal, the screen works perfect.  How can I execute this command on startup?  I did see several other questions about this, but each ends up with using rc.local.  This has been deprecated and since I'm not much of a programmer, I would rather stay away form writing a bunch of scripts.  I did look into Upstart, but that seems to also be going away and the information isn't very helpful for non-programmers.  I also tried using Startup Applications Preferences, but just adding that command doesn't do the trick.